# Base64 encoding implementation

Tags: c, base64

I am learning C and decided to make an implementation of Base64 encoding according to the info Wikipedia provides about it.

My main question is: should I declare the index_table array inside the `get_base64_digi`t function like `static char index_table[] = "blabla"`?

A general code review would also be appreciated.

**funcs.c**

```
static char index_table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

static char get_index_digit(int x) {
    return index_table[x];
}

char get_base64_digit(const unsigned int base64, int digit_number){

    switch (digit_number){
            case 0:
                    return get_index_digit(base64 >> 18);
            case 1:
                    return get_index_digit((base64 >> 12) & 077);
            case 2:
                    return get_index_digit((base64 >> 6) & 077);
            case 3:
                    return get_index_digit(base64 & 077);
    }

    return '\0';
}
```

**funcs.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char get_base64_digit(unsigned int base64, int digit_number);
```

**main.c**

```
 #include "funcs.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char* text = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : '\0';

    unsigned final, temp;

    int text_len  = strlen(text);
    int remainder = text_len % 3;

    //Iterate over the input string, three characters at a time.
    for (int x = final = temp = 0; x < (remainder == 0 ? text_len : text_len - remainder); x += 3) {

            final = (text[x] << 16) | (text[x+1] << 8) | text[x+2];

            printf("%c%c%c%c",  get_base64_digit(final, 0), get_base64_digit(final, 1), get_base64_digit(final, 2), get_base64_digit(final, 3));

    }

    //Handle the last bytes in case text_len wasn't a multiple of 3
    if (remainder == 1) {
            final = text[text_len-1] << 16; 
            printf("%c%c==\n", get_base64_digit(final, 0), get_base64_digit(final, 1));
    } else if (remainder == 2){ 
            final = (text[text_len-2] << 16) | (text[text_len-1] << 8); 
            printf("%c%c%c=\n",  get_base64_digit(final, 0), get_base64_digit(final, 1), get_base64_digit(final, 2));
    } else
            return 0;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### funcs.h

Neither `funcs.c` nor `funcs.h` require anything from `stdio.h` or `string.h`, so you shouldn't be including those there, move them to `main.c` instead. But you should get into the habit of adding include guards to your headers. So either use this at the top:

```
#pragma once
```

Or, to be completely standard and portable:

```
#ifndef FUNCS_H
#define FUNCS_H

// contents of header here

#endif // FUNCS_H
```

#### funcs.c

The static encode mapping is fine as you have it, but would also be fine inside the `get_index_digit` function (static also of course). Since that is the only direct user, it would be slightly better inside in my opinion.

I'd change your signature and preamble for the encoder to:

```
#include <assert.h>
// ...

char get_base64_digit(const unsigned int base64, unsigned int digit_number)
{
  assert(digit_number < 4);
  // ...
```

Passing a negative index or anything greater than 3 is a programming error, it should be caught as early as possible and be a hard failure.

You can get rid of the switch by collapsing all cases:

```
return get_index_digit((base64 >> (18 - 6*digit_number)) & 077);
```

Note that this masks the bits even for the zero case, which is safer. But you might want instead to assert on the fact that the bits above index 18 are all zeros - slightly different contract. (I'd prefer just masking them off though.)

#### main.c

```
char* text = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : '\0';
```

That `'\0'` is bad. Happens to work, but doesn't convey the right information. `text` is a pointer, not a char. Replace with:

```
char* text = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : NULL;
```

But that's actually not a good idea either. What you actually need is an empty string (or bail out).

```
const char* text = argc == 2 ? argv[1] : "";
```

Then you have:

```
unsigned final, temp;
```

But you're not using `temp` anywhere, except for setting it to zero. And you're always initializing `final` to zero in the for loop. So to help simplifying that `for` a bit:

```
unsigned final = 0;
```

Also a slight inconsistency: you're using `unsigned` here, but used `unsigned int` in the declaration for `get_base64_digit` - pick one version and stick to that (they are completely identical).

As for the loop:

```
for (int x = final = temp = 0; x < (remainder == 0 ? text_len : text_len - remainder); x += 3) {
```

That line is too long, and more complex than it needs to be. Removing `final` and `temp` will help:

```
for (int x = 0; x < (remainder == 0 ? text_len : text_len - remainder); x += 3) {
```

And might help you to see that the conditional is unnecessary. If `remainder` is zero, `text_len` and `text_len - remainder` have the same value. So:

```
for (int x = 0; x < text_len - remainder; x += 3) {
```

Or move that subtraction out of the loop for an even simpler structure.

The last lines are a bit odd:

```
} else
        return 0;

return 0;
```

Remove the `else`, it is not useful. Also mixing braced and non-braced blocks in an `if/else` chain isn't a good idea. This is a matter of style, but always using braces is usually safer. If you want to omit them for single-statement blocks, only do that if you only have single-statement blocks in the `if/else` chain.

Last tidbit: you sometimes have `){` (no space), and sometimes `) {` (one space). Stick to one, preferably the one with the space. You also sometimes have an empty line at the start of blocks, sometimes not. If you feel like a bit of vertical separation is good there, try putting the `{` that starts the block on its own line (as I did in the `get_base64_digit` above), and look at the Linux coding style guidelines for some other tips that you may, or may not :-), like.

[`clang-format`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) is an excellent auto-format tool, and a lot of dev tools (including Vim and Emacs) can be made to use it. Try it out.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this review! I can't describe how insightful this has been to me :)

Answer (score 4):

Some additional thoughts after [@Mat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/119849/29485) fine answer.

1. When implementing an algorithm that counts on a particular size of integer, better to use a size that is guaranteed to work, or consider fixed size types.  `unsigned` may only be 16-bit.  Insufficient for the task.

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>

   // unsigned finalfinal;
   // Options in order of (my) preference
   uint32_t      finalfinal;
   unsigned long finalfinal;
   uint_fast32_t finalfinal;
   ```
2. For maximum portability, consider that 16-bit machines are very popular in the embedded world in 2016, so do not assume `unsigned/int` math is at least 32-bit, code to C spec which says an `unsigned` may only be 16-bit.   A 16-bit shift of `text[x]`, which is promoted to `int`, may not work.

   ```
   // finalfinal = (text[x] << 16) | (text[x+1] << 8) | text[x+2];
   finalfinal = (text[x]*1UL << 16) | (text[x+1]*1UL << 8) | text[x+2];
   //  or 
   finalfinal = text[x];
   finalfinal <<= 8; 
   finalfinal |= text[x+1];
   finalfinal <<= 8; 
   finalfinal |= text[x+2];

   // final = text[text_len-1] << 16;
   final = text[text_len-1]*1UL << 16;
   ```
3. Recommend similar thoughts for the function parameters, variables too.

   ```
   // char get_base64_digit(const unsigned int base64, int digit_number)
   int get_base64_digit(const uint32_t base64, unsigned digit_number)
   ```
4. Extending the code to non-null character terminated sources.  Current code works fine for test, yet all the following code should be wrapped in a function with the data pointer and size passed in.

   ```
   char* text = ...
   size_t text_len = strlen(text);

   // Something like this is the real function you need
   int status = NMK64_encode(text, text_len);
   ```
5. `funcs.c` is not distinctive.  How about `NMK_Base64.c`?
6. Minor stuff follows
7. Use matching type.  `strlen()` return type `size_t`, not `int`.

   ```
   // int text_len  = strlen(text);
   // int remainder = text_len % 3;
   size_t text_len  = strlen(text);
   size_t remainder = text_len % 3;
   ```
8. Make `const`

   ```
   // static char index_table[] = ...
   static const char index_table[] = ...
   ```
9. Make `static`.  Would not expect this helper function to have global usage.  Expect `NMK64_encode(text, text_len)` to be the global interface.

   ```
   // get_base64_digit(
   static int get_base64_digit( ...
   ```